# SQL Batched Updates to large table with many indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-optimization

We have a table with 18 columns, 7 of them bit columns, with over 100 million rows. It has 6 non-clustered indexes, 5 of which have the column I need to update.

The primary key (clustered) is a uniqueidentifier, called EntityID

I need to update one of the bit flags on this table using a different table which contains the values I need to sync. My manager asked me to write the update to run in batches since even the smallest of updates take a while due to all the indexes and the shear number of rows in the table. He also asked that the update run based on the EntityID sorted ASC, he mentioned something about reducing the number of pages being read.

I've written probably 5 different versions of a sorted batched update, and they work, but I'm interested to see if there is already a well polished template I could use to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 1 
while(@@rowcount > 0)
begin
    update top (100000) t
    set t.bit = s.bit 
    from table t 
    join tbls s 
      on s.EntityID = t.EntityID 
     and t.bit != s.bit
end
```

I would advise against sorting.  Let the query optimizer do its thing.

If you have any t.bit is null I would do that separate as an `or` slows down the update.

I suggest you disable all the indexes, update, and then enable in indexes.

Comment: I don't have the ability to disable the indexes. This is a very heavily used table on a production database. And by sorting, I meant...sort your source values by the primary key, then take your batches in that order, that way you reduce the overall number of pages hit when you perform your updates.

Comment: @chadwin Can you ask the person who does have access? Disabling and then rebuilding indexes should make a difference. Explain to them why you need to do it.

Comment: This update process just does not have high enough importance to merit disabling 5 indexes on a 100 million record table that's hit by users and applications thousands of times a day, then rebuilding the indexes. This is a process that will run every day.

Comment: @chadwin You don't know that disable then enable is not practical until you test.  This will fragment indexes all those indexes.  I will hold with don't sort - query optimizer is probably smarter than you.

Comment: I'm only saying to sort the order of the source values before creating the batch of records to update, this is what I've been asked to do. So if I have 250,000 records that I need to update...then sort the 250,000 by EntityID, and take the TOP 10,000 records, join on entityid, update those, then take the next 10,000 records, join on entityid, update those. That is how my manager / the System Architect has asked me to do it. I'm only looking for a well polished script that covers that. Otherwise I'll just use my own code.

Comment: If you had code you wanted to polish then why did you not post it?  I bet my simpler answer will be faster.  PK is the physical order of a table.  Query optimizer is not going to go stupid and start splashing around.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do some testing, and it really depends on if you can stop other queries during this time, but quite often it's *much* faster to

- drop the indexes
- do the inserts/updates
- recreate the indexes